# Set parent forms FormElement.TitleBar.BackColor from child form

Tags: c#, telerik, windows-forms-designer

I have a form FrmMain, which has a child form displayed within a PageView, FrmChild. I am trying to set the FrmMain's: this.FormElement.TitleBar.BackColor from FrmChild.

**FrmChild**

```
private void SetWarning() {
    FrmMain.SetTitleBarColor(true);
}
```

**FrmMain**

```
public void SetTitleBarColor(bool warning) {
    if (warning) {
        this.FormElement.TitleBar.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

I tried setting FrmMain.SetTitleBarColor to static, but then I couldn't access the instance of the form.

Comment: though not correct but since you raising invoking child from parent you can pass instance of parent form to child and access the properties their.

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found here: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283100/what-is-the-correct-way-to-change-properties-in-a-parent-form-from-a-child-form)

The correct way to update the parent form is through bubbling. Have the parent form listen for an event from the child form and have the parent update itself.  Any parameters needed can be passed through the EventArgs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).